# HashMap - getting all the values associated with a key

Tags: java, hashmap

I created a HashMap where each key contains an ArrayList as a value. I'm having trouble understanding how to fetch the ArrayList associated with a key and get all the values stored in it.  See below the error I am getting when running the program.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Flights {

private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> flights = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

private void readFlights(String filename) {
    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        while (true) {
            String line = bf.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                String fromCity = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("-"));
                String toCity = line.substring(line.indexOf(">") + 2);
                ArrayList<String> city = flights.get(fromCity);
                if (city != null) {
                    city.add(toCity);
                } else {
                    ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
                    destinations.add(toCity);
                    flights.put(fromCity, destinations);
                }
            }

        }
        bf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void printCities() {
    Iterator<String> fi = flights.keySet().iterator();
    while (fi.hasNext()) {
        String next = fi.next();
        System.out.println(next + "-> "+ flights.get(next));
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
private void printWelcome() {
    System.out
            .println("Welcome to the flight planner.\nHere is a list of all of our cities:");
    printCities();
    System.out.print("Enter the starting city.");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("from " + input + " you can fly directly to:");
    printAvailableFlights(input);
}

private void printAvailableFlights(String city) {
    ArrayList<String> origin = flights.get(city);
    for (String cities: origin) {
        System.out.println(cities);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flights f = new Flights();
    f.readFlights("flights.txt");
    f.printWelcome();
}

}
```

Here is the flights.txt file:

```
San Jose -> San Francisco
San Jose -> Anchorage

New York -> Anchorage
New York -> San Jose
New York -> San Francisco
New York -> Honolulu

Anchorage -> New York
Anchorage -> San Jose

Honolulu -> New York
Honolulu -> San Francisco

Denver -> San Jose

San Francisco -> New York
San Francisco -> Honolulu
San Francisco -> Denver
```

And here is what I see in the console when running the program:

```
Welcome to the flight planner.
Here is a list of all of our cities:
Honolulu -> [New York, San Francisco]
Denver -> [San Jose]
Anchorage -> [New York, San Jose]
San Francisco -> [New York, Honolulu, Denver]
New York -> [Anchorage, San Jose, San Francisco, Honolulu]
San Jose -> [San Francisco, Anchorage]
Enter the starting city.Denver
from Denver you can fly directly to:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Flights.printAvailableFlights(Flights.java:64)
at Flights.printWelcome(Flights.java:59)
at Flights.main(Flights.java:72)
```

Comment: You should use google Guava's Multimap - if you can http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: Why?  What is wrong with HashMap?

Comment: Not related to your question, but I feel I should point out that you are not mapping a key to multiple values, you are mapping a key to a `List`.

Comment: You should build a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't include the distraction/complexity of reading from a file and dealing with exceptions.

Comment: What data is in the file?  What are you passing to `printAvailableFlight()`?  My hunch is that you aren't trimming whitespace when you build your map.

Comment: `When I assign the 'origin' value in the printAvailableFlights method it returns null`  What do you mean it returns null?  You dereference it on the next line, so if it `flights.get(city)` returns null, you will get a NPE.  Are you saying the list is empty?

Comment: where is your entryset?

Comment: #azurefrog, yes you are right, and I'm trying to access the List so that I can iterate through it and get all the values.

Comment: Could it be that the city just does not exist in the map?  This may not be an algorithm problem, but a data problem.  Or the substring logic for parsing your file could be wrong.

Comment: You only ever store one item in a `List`.  Each time through your loop you throw away the old `List` and add a new one to the map with one city in it.  Also, when city is not null, you don't add *anything* to your map.

Comment: This is not thread-safe.  Somebody had to say it.

Comment: @Brandon: So?  Lots of code isn't thread-safe.  It's probably not an issue.

Comment: Not related to the question above, why do people down vote a question although it's a valid question which doesn't conflict with the site's rules?

Comment: From the off-topic description: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: I expect the downvotes are coming from the fact that you haven't provided a runnable example, nor a sample of the file you are reading.  You'll notice that no answers have been posted yet, but there's plenty of conjecture in the comments.  This is because you haven't provided enough information to accurately diagnose your problem.

Comment: Thanks #azurefrog, I find your clarification much more helpful than a bunch of down votes.  I'll do my best next time I post.

Comment: @user2573222: You still have time to edit *this* post.

Comment: Okay, I edited the post.  Hopefully this gives enough information to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
String fromCity = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("-"));
```

leaves a space after the starting city because that is how your text file is formatted. Your keys look like `"Denver "` and `"San Jose "`. You should change it to this:

```
String fromCity = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("-") - 1);
```

Additionally, it would make more sense to use the entire delimiter `" -> "` because some cities have a dash in them, such as [Wilkes-Barre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkes-Barre,_Pennsylvania).

`NullPointerException` is thrown because `Map` returns null if the key doesn't exist. You should account for that in `printAvailableFlights`.

Comment: Thank you #Radiodef, you brought an end to a two hour hair pulling session.  Sweet!